# How do I delete "Custom Sessions" after a MobaXTerm upgrade?

Tags: windows, mobaxterm

I recently updated my MobaXTerm version to v22.2 (build 5008); I had a much older version before, maybe even 12.x.

After the update, my session tree seems to be duplicated: I see my sessions once as "Custom Sessions", then again as "User Sessions". I can edit, add or delete User Sessions - but I can't seem to do that for Custom Sessions with the right-click menus or the menu bar.

How can I get rid of the Custom Sessions? Individually or entirely?

What I've tried:

- Running MobaXTerm as administrator - still no UI for deleting these sessions
- Looking at my user's MobaXTerm.ini - nothing relevant there
- Looking in the MobaXTerm program files folder - I don't see an editable configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom sessions are listed in a file named `Custom.bookmarks.ini` - but it's not immediately located in the Program Files folder. It's compressed as part of a file named `Custom.mxtpro`. That file is actually a ZIP file. To remove it:

1. Close MobaXTerm
2. Make a copy of `Custom.mxtpro` in case you want to later restore the custom sessions
3. Start a ZIP-archive-manipulator application, e.g. [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) - as Administrator
4. Open `Custom.mxtpro` in your  application as a ZIP file
5. Delete, within the ZIP, the `Custom.bookmarks.ini` file
6. Save the changes to `Custom.mxtpro`

When you next start MobaXTerm, the custom sessions will be gone; only user sessions will remain.